# Objects after inject is null

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I am trying to inject objects that are singletons to 2 activity.
My problem is, Milk and Coffee object after @Inject are null into Activity.
In my opinion I miss something.
Please help me and tell me what is missing in the code

AppComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {CoffeeModule.class, MilkModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder appModule(MyMvpApp myMvpApp);

        AppComponent build();

    }
    void inject(MyMvpApp app);
}
```

CoffeeModule:

```
@Module
public class CoffeeModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Coffee getCoffee(){
        return new Coffee();
    }

}
```

MilkModule:

```
@Module
public class MilkModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Milk getMilk(){
        return new Milk();
    }

}
```

My class App:

```
public class MyMvpApp extends Application{

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        initDagger();
    }

    private void initDagger() {
        AppComponent appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .appModule(this)
                .build();
        appComponent.inject(this);
    }

}
```

And my Activity on which these objects are null:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    Milk milk;

    @Inject
    Coffee coffee;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Log.i("tag", "" + milk + coffee);
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't be there a  ...inject(this) statement in the LoginActivity ?

Comment: how to "...inject(this)" into activity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {CoffeeModule.class, MilkModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {

  void inject(LoginActivity app);

  @Component.Builder
  interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance
    Builder appModule(MyMvpApp myMvpApp);

    AppComponent build();
  }
}



public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Inject
  Milk milk;

  @Inject
  Coffee coffee;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule((MyMvpApp) getApplicationContext()).build().inject(this);
    Log.i("tag", "" + milk + coffee);
  }
}


public class MyMvpApp extends Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    initDagger();
  }

  private void initDagger() {
    AppComponent appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
        .appModule(this)
        .build();
  }
}
```

Comment: and I need in every Activity an fragment create DaggerAppComponent.builder ? I saw sometimes AndroidInjection.inject(this), it is this same ?

Comment: may be then you will need to follow a different approach using "dagger.android" package.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add two more lines inside your AppComponent class.

```
void inject(MyMvpApp app);

//you need to provide milk and coffee here
Milk getMilk();
Coffee getCoffee();
```

Edit 1 : one more thing you need to inject your activity too in the app component.

```
void inject(LoginActivity loginActivity);
```

and call the initDagger method in the activity in the same way you are doing in your Application class.

Edit 2 :If you dont want to repeat the whole thing,then create one method in your application class like this:

```
 private AppComponent appComponent ;

 public AppComponent getAppComponent(){
  if (appComponent == null) {
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .appModule(this)
            .build();
    }
    return appComponent;
}

 public void initDagger(){
  appComponent.inject(this);
}
```

Inside onCreate of Application class, call these methods.

```
getAppComponent();
initDagger();
```

Inside your activity, you can do like this rather than initializing the whole module again and again.

```
public void initDagger(){
getApplication().getAppCompoment().inject(this);
}
```

Comment: they are still null after added this 2 line

Comment: ((MyMvpApp)getApplication()).getAppCompoment().inject(this); // to get the result of getAppComponent as Application class has no "getAppCompoment()" method.

Comment: I already mentioned in the edit 2 that you need to write the getAppComponent() in your application class ie class name which is extending Application class

Comment: Yes, thats why it is necessary to specify the class name(used in casting) having the method "getAppCompoment()", because I see getApplication() returns android Application instance not the custom one that extends Application and have method: "getAppCompoment()"